# Renderizar componente al presionar botón con Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Tengo un *dialog* el cual tiene un progressBar con render *false*, y al presionar el botón *Aceptar* cambio el estado a *true* para mostrarlo, pero este se muestra recién cuando se finaliza el *actionListener* y yo quiero que se muestre al momento de presionar.

```
<p:dialog id="dlgGenerarLista" modal="true" height="180" width="500" header="Generar Lista de Trabajo" widgetVar="dlgGenerarLista">
    <p:commandButton onclick="PF('dlgGenerarLista').hide();" value="Cancel" />
    <p:commandButton id="btnAceptarGenerar" value="Accept"
    actionListener="#{crearEstrategiaBeans.GenerarListaTrabajo}"
    oncomplete="PF('dlgGenerarLista').hide();"update="basic"/> 
    <p:panel id="basic" widgetVar="basic">                 
        <p:progressBar rendered="#{crearEstrategiaBeans.visibilidadBarraProgreso}" id="progressBarIndeterminate"  mode="indeterminate"/>
    </p:panel>   
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Suponiendo que mostrar el progressBar no depende de un calculo ni de una llamada a un Bean, puedes poner el progressBar(sin rendered) en otro dialogo y mostrar el dialogo en el onclick/onstart del boton y ocultarlo en el oncomplete del boton.

Comment: @KazMiller había pensado algó así. Si no encuentro uan respuesta lo probaré. Gracias